# Api Managment use case

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have a question about the Azure API Management service and how to use it in terms of security. I have looked and cant find an answer I can feel confident with.

So, should I use subscription keys or an access token with oauth2.

I think having subscription keys on its own is not good enough since the are more of an authentication method, Where as an oauth token can do both.
Furthermore I dont see a use case of using both a subscription key and auth token so I am not sure on what an ideal use case would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APIM itself does not prescribe any specific best way to use it, but provides different options that fit different scenarios. If you're asking about how to authenticate/authorize calls to APIM there are a few ways:

1. Subscription keys. A good way to authenticate calling party and authorize it to make calls to a certain product/API scope. Having option of two keys per subscription allows you an ease of rotating them over time. This is mainly fits scenarios where you either need to authorize end users using APIM alone or where you embed keys into an app that end users use.
2. OAuth. APIM itself can't issue OAuth tokens, so this is mostly fitting when there us a third-party OAuth server available either owned by you or not. Normally APIM would be transparent to OAuth token in request and even can't use it to authenticate call to its internal users database, but you have an option of using validate-jwt policy to require such token, look for certain claims, issues, check signature e.t.c.
3. Client certificates. If you control your clients then you have an option of provisioning client certificates and configure policy at APIM level to require certificate presence, inspect its attributes or validate its chain including ability to provision your own CA and root certificates.
4. IP filtering. Not that high of a security measure, but still an option. You can configure APIM to deny calls made outside of specified IP ranges.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

1. Best Use case is protecting backend APIs via VPN Connectivity. This will provide a secure tunnel between APIM to your backend system (ERP or any other System)
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-vnet
2. Below one also good case for security,
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad

Comment: So, are you suggesting to use only the oauth token and not the subscription keys?

Comment: You can use both. Subscription key is actually only to identify who is consuming the APIs. It will be useful for billing, monitoring and any troubleshooting purpose. It has little bit of security, but not recommended for high security purpose. So in addition to sub key, you have to maintain Outh2.0, VPN or some other security methods proposed by @Vitaliy Kurokhtin